# why feedforward Neural network does not generalized?

Tags: r, neural-network

I made a simple NN predict x from Sin(x). It failed. The NN was successful in predicting sin(x)  form x but could not predict x from Sin(x). in both cases(sin(x) and arcsin(x)) we have a non-linear mapping and NN is supposed[image] to be able to fit any function. so, my question is why the NN failed?  is this a case of underfitting? can I figure out at which point in the training process the divergence happens?

```
set.seed(1234567890)
Var3 <- runif(500, 0, 20)
mydata3 <- data.frame(Sin=sin(Var3),Var=Var3)
set.seed(1234567890)
winit <- runif(5500, -1, 1)
#hidUnit <- c(9,1)
set.seed(1234567890)
nn3 <-neuralnet(formula = Var~Sin,data = mydata3,
                hidden =c(4,2,1),startweights =winit,
              learningrate = 0.01,act.fct = "tanh")

plot(mydata3, cex=2,main='Predicting x from Sin(x)',
     pch = 21,bg="darkgrey",
     ylab="X",xlab="Sin(X)")
points(mydata3[,1],predict(nn3,mydata3), col="darkred", 
       cex=1,pch=21,bg="red")

legend("bottomleft", legend=c("true","predicted"), pch=c(21,21),
       col = c("darkgrey","red"),cex = 0.65,bty = "n")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to predict infinitely many x values from one sin(x) value. Think about it, it's not a function that you are trying to predict. A function maps every x value to exactly one y value. In your case, there are theoretically infinitely many values that x can take on for every sin(x) you feed into the function.

The domain of arcsin(x) is only from -1 to 1 and the range is from -pi/2 to pi/2 radians (not from 0 to 20).

Perhaps constraining your x values to -pi/2 to pi/2 would work.